Toolbar with multiple line of text not aligning with other toolbar item
I'm facing a little bit of a problem customizing the SwiftUI toolbar. First let me share my code and then I will provide you more information.
   // MARK: - Toolbar
.toolbar {
    /// Top bar
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
        Text("")
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
        Button(action: {
            viewModel.presentDismissOnboardingDialog()
        }, label: {
            R.image.abort.image
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
        })
    }
    /// Bottom bar - pager view
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        pagerView
    }
}

.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
        Text(titleText)
            .lineLimit(2)
            .font(.liebherrHeadRegular(size: 24))
            .foregroundColor(.textPrimary)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .frame(alignment: .center)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .padding()
    }
}

So, the ToolbarItem(placement: navigation) is multiline. I want this one and .topBarTrailing one to be aligned on top of each other. I tried many solution but nothing is working. I am sharing a screenshot so that you understand how it looks. Any kind of help is appreciated.

